# No Grass plugin in plugin manager in Qgis 2.14 on windows 7

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, grass-7.0, qgis-2.14

I would like to use the v.net.path algorithm from grass7 with processing into qgis 2.14. It's on my new laptop with windows 7 where I installed qgis 2.14.2 desktop with grass 7.0.3. But I don't find Grass plugin in plugin manager.

Where is the error ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @DidierDebroize! Are you running the `QGIS 2.14.2 Desktop with GRASS 7.0.3` program? If not, you should be able to find this from the **Start** menu.

Comment: Yes, I'm running "QGIS Desktop 2.14.2  with GRASS 7.0.3" program from the start menu.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're running the QGIS Desktop with GRASS the GRASS plugin is not on by default, you have to go to Plugins -> Manage and Install... then to the installed plugins.  There you'll find an entry for GRASS 7, check its box and then you'll have the GRASS tools under the plugin menu.

If you don't have the GRASS 7 entry in the installed plugins go back to OSGEO4W installer, set everything QGIS and GRASS related to uninstall, uninstall, close OSGEO4W, then re-run and re-install QGIS and GRASS.

Comment: Hi,I tried the different solutions, but the problem is still here. Maybe a problem of postintall.log file.

Comment: Hi Everybody, I come back after having read this post :  http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14795. It says that using 2.14.3 version standalone installer will make the job. So I tested and it does ! Grass7 plugin appears and seems to work. Great !! Thanks all (I think we can close this question but I don't know how...).